# Do azure functions gracefully shutdown existing function invocations when deploying new function app?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Id like to understand the implications of deploying a new release of a azure function app as it relates to existing function invocations/threads. I understand that with frameworks such as asp.net, there were options such as adding app_office.htm to the root.

How do we ensure that we dont terminate active threads and allow the application to gracefully shutdown before deployment?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** Graceful shutdown is achieved using [cancellation tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#cancellation-tokens). One thing I can't seem to determine is the grace period you have once the cancellation token is issued :(

```
public static class AsyncExample
{
    [FunctionName("BlobCopy")]
    public static async Task RunAsync(
        [BlobTrigger("sample-images/{blobName}")] Stream blobInput,
        [Blob("sample-images-copies/{blobName}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream blobOutput,
        CancellationToken token,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"BlobCopy function processed.");
        await blobInput.CopyToAsync(blobOutput, 4096, token);
    }
}
```

**Option 2** is to use the [durable functions extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-concepts). These extensions provide reliable execution by [maintaining state and using checkpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-checkpointing-and-replay) to allow your functions to restart mid execution after a shutdown or failure. In short, the durable functions checkpoint the state of your function at every await statement and enable replay from the last successful await statement.

**Option 3**  is to use use deployment slots and have a Prod1 and Prod2 slot and alternate deployment. This will allow you built a drain-stop approach to preserve running instances to completion. You will still need to cater for failed instances and unknown exceptions with durable functions or a cancellation token.

**Option 4** is to use two functions app instances and use a load balancer to manage the traffic across them.

Comment: I dont think this is what I am looking for. Im talking about the deployment aspects of ensuring threads dont terminate prematurely. Cancellation tokens are when clients can explicitly request to cancel, which isnt what I am doing. Durable functions is not what I am looking for either. Its more related to host shutdown logic

Comment: What you need for that scenario (and HA) is deployment slots. Have a Prod1 and Prod2 slot and alternate deployment, rhis enables a drainstop approach to oreserve running instances to completion. You will still need to cater for failed instances and unknown exceptions with durables or a cancellation token.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#method-signature-parameters)  if you use cancellation token.

So by default if your AF will go to shutdown it will notify threads about shutdown, if you don't use cancellation token then it will wait some time(I can't find how long) and kill your threads even job is not complete.

Comment: I dont understand. What exactly would I do with a function that is triggered by a queue message when I am deploying a new version. Your saying that i need to somehow send a cancellation token? I dont think this sounds right :/

Comment: Think about how we used to use app_offline.htm. It offers a graceful way to reject incoming requests, but still handle existing thread processing.

Comment: @joey when you AF is going to shut down host will not accept any triggers its the first thing, but if you have any ongoing tasks AF will wait till task is complete.

Comment: @joey same thing is here. This is why Cancellation Token is coming to help. AF host is using it too, to prevent listeners to start new threads, but you also must use it lets say if you have task, send  newsletter which can run for 4 minutes for instance. So if you check cancellation token you should stop and soon as possible and put new message to the queue so after restart AF will pick it up.

Comment: @VovaBilyachat any option if the function is written in NodeJS? I don't see any cancellation token there.